# cant get my desire result of max(like)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i wanted a query where a user can retrieve max like on a post of his particular friend.
means a query can calculate maximum likes in the post of the user's friend and show it (12 june, 123+ likes, Ayan)

SESSION_ID = 17.
ACCEPTED FRIENDS ID= 14,15,16

database image ->

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=879866a

As we can see in the table user 14 got maximum likes (5 likes )
user 15 got 3 likes

Now my query,

```
<?php
               include('config.php');           
        $resultlp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE requested='".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] ."' and status='accepted' ");
            while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($resultlp))
                                  {                 
                                 $qwe=$row3['addedby']; //result to make an array of friends

        //second result (PROBLEM HERE)-->                       
$resultm = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment where  commentid ='$qwe' and like_count= (select max(like_count) from comment where  commentid ='$qwe') ");                
while($rowm1 = mysql_fetch_array($resultm))
        { 
$id=$rowm1['name'];
$lc=$rowm1['like_count'];
$result44 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members where id='$id'");
while($row44 = mysql_fetch_array($result44))
                    { 
        $namel=$row44['fname'];}

                }  }
                ?>
```

the result is fetching the value in  id=64 but it should be fetch the value of id=70 because he gets maximum likes.

suppose I have 3 friends, my id = 17 and friend id (14,15,16)...they made a post...and they get likes.. in the database pic you can see,commentid=14 gets maximum likes(id=70)..i want to fetch that value but instead of this, query getting the value of commentid=15 id=64

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    $resultm = mysql_query("SELECT id,commentid,content,name,MAX(like_count) as max_likes FROM comment where commentid='$qwe' group by commentid ");
```

This query will give you the result row of id 64 for $qwe=15 and row of id 70 for $qwe=14 as the corresponding max like_count.