# mysql rows count by where clause

Tags: php, mysql

look at the database here ---->http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=908d940

in the subcommentid rows, value 63 is repeating maximum time itself 7 times

i want to fetch this value in numerical form means like this

maximum rows in  subcommentid is 7

i hv tried this

```
$query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE where id='63'");
    echo mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

but

but 63 is a variable so how can a server pre decide that 63 is repeating itself maximum nos

nd look at dix ques too [cant get my desire result of max(like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376243/cant-get-my-desire-result-of-maxlike/25376571#25376571)

Comment: "SELECT max(subcommentid) FROM table" ??

Comment: look at d databse means maximum number of rows of a value in subcommenit

Comment: @TBI max(subcommentid) will retuen only max in  "value" but i want max rows, then identify which value is repeating maximum times..! understood?

Comment: @TBI could you just look at dix ques too please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376243/cant-get-my-desire-result-of-maxlike/25376571#25376571

Comment: What *language* is this? "dix ques"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this query -

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT subcommentid,COUNT(*) as count FROM table GROUP BY subcommentid ORDER BY count DESC;");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo $result['subcommentid'].'<br/>'; //subcomment id
echo $result['count']; // number of rows
```

If you want all, store in array -

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $results[$row['subcommentid']] = $row['count'];
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($results);exit;
```

Comment: osm buddy it works, finally thanks for understanding my ques. :)

Comment: i was wondering if you could just look at dix ques too please

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376243/cant-get-my-desire-result-of-maxlike/25376571#25376571

Answer (score 1):

use select count(*) from.....

Or

use mysql function  mysql_num_rows($query_result).

Comment: you dont understand my ques, i want it but from the max """particular """ ("Same value") rows..look at d database

Comment: try this SELECT count(*) FROM comments WHERE subcommentid='63'";

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id=`7`";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_num_rows` function in php to count the no.of rows. Your code should look like this

```
$query=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE where id='63'");
    echo mysqli_num_rows($query); // will echo no.of rows having id 63
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: you dont understand my ques, i want it but from the max """particular """ ("Same value") rows..look at d database

Comment: i think it will help me  but 63 is a variable so how can a server pre decide that 63  is repeating itself maximum nos..understood my ques?